# Browser compatibility; Before or after uploading website to server?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser

I am on the stage where I need to make my website cross-browser compatible.
I need tips on how to get started.

I have developed my website on firefox, so it works great with firefox.

I guess I have to download a couple of versions of all major browsers now, right?
Then just test each browser one by one?

Should I do this before uploading the entire website onto a server or afterwards?

All tips and SW which makes this easier is appreciated.

BTW, it is a classifieds website using MySql, Solr, PHP, js etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-browser compatibility is best planned for in advance, as there are ways to build your site that will make it much easier.

- Consider using a CSS reset script like [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html).
- Consider using a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).
- You can make use of [Adobe BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html) to do cross-browser testing.
- Consider the mobile audience.

Comment: Whats the css reset script for?

Comment: It makes it easier to write a proper site to begin with, although it doesn't help to test it.

Comment: The reason for a CSS reset is that all browsers have presentation defaults, but browsers don't necessarily have the *same* defaults. See http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/

Comment: I thought CSS reset was a great idea years ago, but now I'm starting to think it's too heavy handed, not to mention with so many browsers being more up to date, not as necessary.  I fully agree with using jQuery, it's the safest way to be mass browser compatible, as well as having the fastest JS possible, it's a total win-win library.

Comment: Is adobe BrowserLab FULLY reliable, or do I need to make tests with actual browsers also?

Comment: @Camran: BrowserLab is just a first-level sanity check. if you have a logged-in state, it will be of little help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some kind of local webserver so you can edit the code and test it in a comfortable way. It is also helpful if you make it accessible for validator.w3.org so you can do syntax checking.

Testing it in IE6, 7 and 8, Firefox and Chrome would be a good start I would say.

Comment: There's no need to use the online W3C validator when the "HTML Validator" plugin for Firefox exists, no public URL needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with server side code, you need to have a server.

Once the site goes live you will need both a live and a development server.

Comment: I have a development server... If wampserver counts as one!

Comment: It does, although the fewer differences there are between the development server and live server, the better. I try to keep a VM configured identically to the production server for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd make it cross browser compatible before uploading to the server. The reason for this is that you may need to change the server-side code, adding ids and classes to the markup, plus it may well be necessary to change the markup. Make sure it's working locally first.

[IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) is very useful for testing on the various IE browsers. I'd ensure that I've tested it on a Webkit browser (such as Chrome), a Gecko Browser (such as Firefox) and Opera. See [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers) for different browsers.